# Wait for multiple RxJava observable's to complete

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous, rx-java

I'm using RxJava in a web service to create multiple observables, each that do something during it's onNext and onError functions. I want to wait until all of these observables finish completing its work before returning a response to the client, but I also want these tasks to be executed in parallel

I've merged all of these using:

`Observable<List<Obj>> mergedObs = Observable.mergeDelayError(tasks)`

I then convert this into a blocking observable via

```
mergedObs.toList().toBlocking.subscribe(...)
```

However, I've noticed that while the merged observable waits for all tasks to call subscribe(), it *does not* wait for the tasks within the subscribe function to complete. Here's some sample code with unimportant details omitted:

```
public void doWork() {
    Observable<Obj> mergedTasks = getTasks();
    mergedTasks.toList().toBlocking().subscribe(
        results -> LOG.info("Done!)
    );

    return; // eventually returns a web response
}

private Observable<Obj> getTasks() {
    List<Observable<Obj>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    Observable<Obj> task1 = getTask1();
    Observable<Obj> task2 = getTask2();
    tasks.add(task1);
    tasks.add(task2);

    // Both tasks execute in parallel
    tasks.toList().subscribe(
        result -> processSearch(), // this can execute after the service returns a response!
        exception -> handleException() // this can execute after the service returns a response!
    );

    return Observable.mergeDelayError(tasks);
}

private Observable<Obj> getTask1() {
    // implementation detail
}

private Observable<Obj> getTask2() {
    // implementation detail
}
```

While this code *does* wait for both tasks to call subscribe(), it doesn't wait for the work performed within the onSuccess or onError.

Comment: What exactly should wait for the tasks and the subscribe to finish? `toBlocking` already makes sure of that.

Comment: The main thread should wait. It looks like the main thread waits for all the tasks to call subscribe() before proceeding, AKA it doesn't execute LOG.info("Done!") until all the subscribes are called. However, the work being done within the task's subscribe still executes asynchronously, so the return statement in doWork() executes before the work within the getTasks() subscribe()

Comment: Use `ForkJoin` for that

Comment: Why are you executing `tasks` twice (one as `tasks.toList().subscribe()`, one as `mergedTasks.toList().toBlocking().subscribe()`?

Comment: mergedTasks.toList().toBlocking().subscribe() executes once, once all the tasks are completed